# Data Binding Command to LLS in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, data-binding, mvvm, windows-phone-8, command

In summary, I am trying to bind a command to a data template.  I want the user to tap the block of data, and a command in my View Model will be fired.

I have pasted (poor) code on binding a button to my View Model command, but I'm unclear on how to bind the tapping of the entire block of data without the button.

Basically, I want the user to simply tap the StackPanel holding the textblocks to fire the LoadDataCommand.  I do not want the button in the stack panel firing the command.  The code below is not my usual coding practices, I am just experimenting... fyi :)

I am developing for WP8.  I am NOT using MVVM Light.  I have already tried using MVVM Light library only's EventToCommand, but apparently it doesn't work with WP8.  Any suggestions would be appreciated!

```
        <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="CredList" Margin="0,300,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding DataSource}">
        <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,15,0,0">
                        <Button Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.LoadDataCommand, ElementName=CredList}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Username}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Password}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <Line X1="2" Y1="0" X2="1" Y2="0" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="AntiqueWhite" StrokeThickness="0.5" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector>
```

Comment: EventToCommand does work with WP8. Who says it doesn't?

Comment: I get this error:Type 'EventToCommand' from assembly 'GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WP8' is built with an older version of the Blend SDK, and is not supported in a Windows Presentation Framework 8 project.  I downloaded MVVM Light libraries only (v4.1.27.1) directly from NuGet

Comment: Have you tried using the SelectionChanged event of the LLS?

Comment: @ShawnKendrot yes, the SelectionChanged event works but I want to bind it to my View Model.  I suppose I will just use the SelectionChanged event and stop trying to be a XAML purist *sigh*.  Maybe in VS2013 for WP there will be better support for command bindings.  Thanks all.

Comment: It's OK to have some code-behind. When you use XAML, it still generates code :) But I agree it's nice to keep things clean in XAML. I try for this often